# will chrome.socket support multicast sockets?

Tags: sockets, google-chrome

chrome.socket is an experimental API that enables chrome extensions to access UDP and TCP sockets, see:

```
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/socket.html
```

Will it support multicast sockets?

I am hoping the answer is yes, since that will enable extensions to implement discovery on local area networks, e.g. for UPnP devices like TVs. It would also enable peer to peer gaming apps for people on the same local area network, where multicast sockets are used for invitations to join an existing game session, and for efficient transmission of game play between players.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, IP multicast well works in chrome.experimental.socket :)

Sample UPnP M-Search code:
https://github.com/KensakuKOMATSU/chrome-upnp/blob/master/extension/javascripts/upnp.js

Please note that currently above code only works in chromium's specific revision ( See detail on readme.md in above repositry )